# How to add ajaxcontroltoolkit to toolbox in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used the ajaxtoolkit with .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010, and I was able to add a new tab to the toolbox and add the ajaxtoolkit controls to the toolbox. How do I do this in Visual Studio 2012?

I have added the ajaxtoolkit with [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet), but I would like to see the controls in the toolbox, so I can drag the controls in. How is this done?

Comment: are you sure this is a MVC question vs webforms question?

Answer (score 39):

It's located in the packages folder created by Visual Studio 2012 after you use NuGet Package Manager to download it.

Create a tab in Visual Studio (you can name it Ajax Toolkit).

[image]

Right click on it and select: Choose Items..

[image]

Click Browse and navigate to the packages folder that Visual Studio 2012 creates with your source. Something like this: ..\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.7.0123\lib\40\AjaxControlToolkit.dll

[image]

[image]

Select AjaxControlToolKit.

Comment: Just in case someone wonders where is the location of the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. In you solution folder (where the .sln file exists) you should find a folder called packages, inside this folder you will find AjaxControlToolkit.7.1213 (or some other version number). From the lib folder use the DLL that matches the project .Net framework version.

Comment: i followed the same steps and it gave me an error saying could not find any suitable components in AjaxToolKit.dll

Answer (score 9):

I just installed it in Visual Studio 2013. Here's a summary of the process:

1. Click on solution and Manage Nuget Packages
2. Filter for AJAX and select the Ajax Control Toolkit
3. After NuGet installs this, it won't be in the toolbox!
4. Create a new toolbox group for AJAX CONTROL TOOLKIT
5. *Add Items*
6. *Browse*
7. Navigate to the toolkit URL. Project is Webapplication1 in the c:\temp folder so the toolkit was in: C:\temp\WebApplication1\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.7.1213\lib\45 (because I am using framework 4.5)
8. Click OK and the toolbox should be populated.

Answer (score 4):

Slight sort cut for finding the dll folder, for example step 7 in the instruction set given by user3546149.

(Good job, I would up vote your answer but no reputation).

AjaxControlTookkit should show under References for the project.  Right click it and select Properties. The Path property is the path to the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. Copy that Path property.Then for step 7 paste the Path property directly in the search box.  Saves eye strain and clickity click oops syndrome.

(Works for VS 2013 also, maybe others).

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the AJAX Control Toolkit does everything to install itself into the VS toolbox. First exit out of VS (it will tell you to exit if you don't) then click the Download button in [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://devexpress.com/act).

Answer (score -1):

To install Ajax Control Toolkit, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit
```

this is install the Ajaxtoolkit in your current project..