# Cannot add AjaxContrlToolkit into Toolbox in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have added AjaxControlToolkit for .NET 4 into my web form project through Nuget. But I cannot add the controls into my Toolbox in Visual Studio. The steps of adding the controls I used are exactly same with the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258994/how-to-add-ajaxcontroltoolkit-to-toolbox-in-vs-2012#new-answer), but after I selected the .dll file and click "Open", this error keep coming up:

**There are no components in 'My Project Location\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.7.0725\lib\40\AjaxControlToolkit.dll' that can be placed on the toolbox.**

My project is using .NET 4 also, I have checked it. I have done some research but there is no solution for this problem online! I also tried to add the toolkit from the zip file downloaded from the official website, same error! I don't know whether it is a Visual Studio problem. Please help me! This troublesome mystery has puzzled me for many days...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find the answer?  i want the controls in my toolbox too.

Comment: No I didn't...I moved on to use jQuery for ajax calls. It seems this problem is weird and rarely happened. I think it is not the toolkit's problem, it should be a bug from VS.

Answer (score 0):

try this new Ajaxtoolkit.......
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/109918