# how to Maximize/Minimize separate sections in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing one ASP.NET Web Page in that I Want to show data, as it is in the attached link. So Please go through it. 
So I want the similar functionality in my We Page also.

As We can see here I have separate section for Store Details, POS Details, Registered Banks Details and so on. And If I click on +/- symbol, I should be able to maximize and minimize that particular section.

Actually I am very new to Asp.net, I have learned things by myself only so far, Nobody here to guide me. 
So I have no idea how to do this?
What to do and what items I need to select from toolbox in Visual Studio.
I have idea about PAnel Control , but with panel control I am not able to get maximize and minimize functionality here. 
Please help me out .

Thanks

!(http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img542/4391/spx1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use **AJAX Toolkit controls** (ToolkitScriptManager and CollapsiblePanelExtender). And for that do following steps:

(1)**Learn and Download AJAX Toolkit** from 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ or 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx or 
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/15258994/how-to-add-ajaxcontroltoolkit-to-toolbox-in-vs-2012
(2)**Add toolkit into your project and create one example** with any one control of the toolkit
(3)**Try below example** as you want

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCPTop" runat="server" Width="500">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    POS DETAILS
                </td>
                <td align="right" valign="top">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTop" runat="server">(Show Details...)</asp:Label>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgTop" runat="server" AlternateText="(Show Details...)" ImageUrl="App_Themes/Default/images/expand_blue.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlTop" runat="server" Width="500">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    TID :
                </td>
                <td>
                    abc...
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    xyz ...
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpTop" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnlTop"
        BehaviorID="cpTop" CollapseControlID="pnlCPTop" Collapsed="False" CollapsedImage="App_Themes/Default/images/expand_blue.jpg"
        CollapsedText="(Show Details...)" ExpandControlID="pnlCPTop" ExpandedImage="App_Themes/Default/images/collapse_blue.jpg"
        ExpandedText="(Hide Details...)" ImageControlID="imgTop" SuppressPostBack="True"
        TextLabelID="lblTop">
    </cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

**In web config**

```
<system.web>
 <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

I hope this may helps you. I suggest to first learn AJAX Toolkit and then add to tool box and then try above code.

Another way is using javascript like below:

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function funHide() {
            document.getElementById('imgShow').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('trPOSDETAILS').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('imgHide').style.display = 'none';
        }
        function funShow() {
            document.getElementById('imgShow').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('trPOSDETAILS').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('imgHide').style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
```

**aspx or html**

```
<table width="500px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'>
                POS DETAILS
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <img id='imgShow' src='App_Themes/Default/images/expand_blue.jpg' alt='Show Details...' onclick="funShow()" style='display:none;'/>
                <img id='imgHide' src='App_Themes/Default/images/collapse_blue.jpg' alt='Hide Details...' onclick="funHide()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trPOSDETAILS">
            <td>TID :</td>
            <td>abc...</td>
            <td>Name :</td>
            <td>xyz ...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Please mark this answer useful if this solve your problem.**

Comment: Thanks a lot Pankaj
Cant it be done without using Ajax Toolkit ?

Comment: Without Ajax Toolkit you can try javascript as mentioned in updated answer.