# ASP.NET 4.5 How do I use an Ajax controls, I can't find them in the Toolbox?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, .net-4.5

total newbie to AJAX, I got the NuGET an I found the Ajax Control Toolkit
7.1213.0

I ran this    PM> Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit 
It said successful at the end. 
There is nothing to add if I right click a TAB in the toolbox and look in the .NET Framework components.

It says The Ajax Control Toolkit contains more than 40 controls, including...  Where do I see them and how do I add them to my WEB page?
I see an 'AJAX Extensions' tab in my Toolbox which was there already, but there are not 40 controls. Just these
Pointer, Scriptmanager, ScriptManagerProxy, Timer, UpdatePanel, UpdatProgress

Are these suppose to be controls I can drag onto my WEB page or how do they work?

Comment: ASP.NET Ajax is now on nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to take a look at the [sample](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/AutoComplete).

Second, you have to download  the [AJAX-Control-Toolkit](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/) and you will find example projects.

How to add it to ToolBox.

[How to add ajaxcontroltoolkit to toolbox in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258994/how-to-add-ajaxcontroltoolkit-to-toolbox-in-vs-2012)

Comment: Thank you I also found this YouTube vid>>> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfctpFbZU1o showing that as well, I now have them, But I don't know where to store the AjaxControlToolkit.dll so it not just in "a" project but available always without having to redo this everytime.

Comment: @R2Builder Just UNZIP downloaded file and you can open solution. Build project and you have all stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the controls in you tool bar. You can go through this link.

http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/04/16/installing-ajax-control-toolkit-4-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx