# Nuget: AjaxControlToolKit issues

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Reference details and answers in >[How to add ajaxcontroltoolkit to toolbox in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258994/how-to-add-ajaxcontroltoolkit-to-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2012/30090784#30090784)
is anyone able to help please?

Hi thanks for the above but I am running into issues, I have VS express 2013 for Web and have a webforms application that I have installed ajaxcontroltoolkit using Nuget but then when I try to add the controls to the toolbox there is no dll or any folders under the ajaxcontroltoolbox folder in the packages element of my application root folder. am I missing something, do I need to download and install ajaxcontroltoolkit separately? also does the ajax control toolbox support application using webforms or only weboste using webforms>?
 many thanks Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You probably downloaded a NuGet package when it was in transitional state before DevExpress released v15.1. Try to download it now, it must contain .dll.

Anyway, I advise you using .NET Framework 4.0 or higher to avoid downloading ancient AjaxContolToolkit NuGet package v.8.0 that in not maintained anymore.